# Width giving a different result while/after loading the page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set the margin-left of a specific div (let's call it: div1) to be:

```
-1 * $('.div2 canvas').width()/2
```

So I am using the following line of code to do that:

```
$('#div1').css('margin-left', -1 * $('.div2 canvas').width()/2);
```

Once the page is loaded the result it gives me is -150. However, if I run the same exact line of code in the Chrome console, it gives the right result: -360 since the total width of div2 is 720.

I tried adding:

```
$(window).load(function () { });
```

or

```
$('#div1').load(function () { });
```

or

```
$('.div2 canvas').load(function () { });
```

but that did not help.

My assumption is that the width of div2 is changing based on some sort of information that is being injected and that once the page is ready the total width of the div 720px (in this example) but I am not entirely sure how to run this line of code once the whole page has been loaded and everything has been injected.

Comment: Do you really know to format your question?

Comment: Is there a better way of formatting this question? I would appreciate some guidance :) thanks!

Comment: Did it for you. :) I meant code formatting. :)

Comment: Now regarding your question. Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with what you have done? It would be easy for us. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function () { });
```

should have helped. You also might try

```
$(document).ready(function () { });
```

but if that doesn't help, you'll need to show us your page (or a demo containing the problem) and the code which injects things after that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to wrap this code in a document ready callback.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Your code
}
```

This ensures that the html is loaded, however it does not care about loaded images, which is where .load comes in. If your div contains image tags, you'll need two callbacks.

```
$(document).ready(function () { // Ensures that your document is loaded
    $('.div2 canvas').load(function () { // Ensures that the images within our tag are loaded
        // Your code
    }
}
```

If we do not enclose this second callback definition in document ready, the tag we're referring to $('.div2 canvas') will not exist, and thus no load callback will be bound.

Comment: For some reason, this did not work at all (didn't even get the 150 px it used to get) ...